# how do I get non-server values mapped back from client?

Tags: breeze

I am setting properties in client-side Breeze entities.  I see the EntityInfo UnmappedValuesMap collection, which I'd like to use.  It would be great if I could get a few custom client values returned in the Unmapped collection to avoid adding these everywhere.

I am initializing the metastore with:

```
     store.registerEntityTypeCtor("UserInfo", null, userInfoInitializer);

     function userInfoInitializer(userinfo) {
        userinfo.creatingId = ko.observable(0);
        ...
```

I was hoping 'creatingId' would get passed to server.  But nothing extra appears in the net traffic.
I don't think it matters, but on the server I am using Breeze.ContextProvider.

Are there flags somewhere that govern this behavior?  Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add a 'creatingId' to every entity type you could do something like this:

```
metadataStore.getEntityTypes().forEach(
    function(entityType) {

        var ctor = function () {
            this.creatingId = 0;
        };

        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(entityType.name, ctor, null);
    });
```

Note- using a constructor instead of an initializer.  This will ensure the value appears in the unmapped values collection.  Don't worry, breeze will make this an observable property on your entity.